# Turn a point cloud into an image with Python

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,

Recently, I tried to run through the pcl_ros tutorial to convert a point cloud from a Kinect to an image.  My hope is to be able to do the exact same thing in Python, not C++, and then work with the image using the OpenCV Python interface.

here's the tutorial link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage

I hit a small snag, though.  It seems like the tutorial is referencing a Ros Topic from openni_camera called /camera/depth/points2, but I can't seem to find this topic in list of topics published by openni_camera.

Rather, I found:  /camera/depth/points, but this doesn't seem to generate an image when I make this change in the tutorial.

Will getting the image from /camera/depth/points2 be necessary to fulfill my overall goal?

Also, are there any other ways to easily convert a Point Cloud from the Kinect to an image in Python?
Many Thanks in advance for everyone's words of wisdom!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10501/turn-a-point-cloud-into-an-image-with-python/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are currently no PCL-python bindings, so there is no single function to convert a point cloud into an image. You can however subscribe to /camera/depth/image, which is already an image and has 32-bit float valued pixels (values are in meters). It can be converted easily into a cvMat using cv_bridge ([see this post for further details](http://answers.ros.org/question/1189/openni_camera-depth-image-opencv)).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone coming across this now: Python bindings for PCL were released in February of 2013 by Strawlab at
http://strawlab.github.io/python-pcl/

---

Originally posted by [misaugstad](https://answers.ros.org/users/21958/misaugstad/) with karma: 21 on 2015-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2